# how to add more button/link to the feeds in drupal7

Tags: views, feeds

I have more than 10 feeds in my website and I want to display them 3 items at a time. When I go to site information and change the items per page to 3, I see the 3 items and the pagination controls added. Now I want to add a *more* button/link instead of the pagination controls.